# Amazon Athena error when creating partitioned tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I am new to Athena.

I have multiple CSV files in the following format. Note all fields are in double quotes. And total file size is about 5GB. If possible, I would rather do this without the use of Glue. Unless there is a reason to spend $ on running the crawlers.

```
"emailusername.string()","emaildomain.string()","name.string()","details.string()"
"myname1","website1.com","fullname1","address1 n details"
"myname2","website2.com","fullname2","address2 n details"
```

The following code on Athena works perfectly:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db1.tablea (
  `emailusername`  string,
  `emaildomain`  string,
  `name` string,
  `details` string 
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("separatorChar" = ",", "escapeChar" = "\\")
LOCATION 's3://projectzzzz2/0001_aaaa_delme/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

However I am neither able to cluster, nor use partitioning. The following code runs successfully. Post that I am also able to Load Partitions successfully. But no data is returned!

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db1.tablea (
  `name` string,
  `details` string 
)
PARTITIONED BY (emaildomain string, emailusername string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("separatorChar" = ",", "escapeChar" = "\\")
LOCATION 's3://projectzzzz2/0001_aaaa_delme/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');

MSCK REPAIR TABLE tablea;
SELECT * FROM "db1"."tablea";
```

**Result: Zero records returned**

Comment: I got your first `CREATE TABLE` working against your sample data file. However, the first row was included in results, so you should also tell it to skip the first row. I also got the second `CREATE TABLE` command to work fine with no error, but of course I don't have partitioned data to use it with.

Comment: what is the default error?

Comment: Bump! anyone? plshelp

Comment: Show us how the data is organized on S3, e.g. an S3 listing. There's not enough information to answer as it is.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to create partitions on emaildomain, emailusername
You don’t need to have fields called emaildomain, emailusername in the table. However, you need to have 2 directories as domain1/user1 under your s3 location.

e.g. s3://projectzzzz2/0001_aaaa_delme/domain1/user1

make sure
copy your file to s3://projectzzzz2/0001_aaaa_delme ( not to the location s3://projectzzzz2/0001_aaaa_delme/domain1/user1)

then you can issue

ALTER TABLE  tablea ADD PARTITION (emaildomain ='domain1', emailusername= 'user1') location ‘s3://projectzzzz2/0001_aaaa_delme/domain1/user1' ;

If you query the table  tablea you will see new fields called emaildomain and emailusername been added automatically

As of my knowledge, whenever you add a new user or new email domain then you need to copy your file into the new folder and need to issue the ‘Alter table’ statement accordingly.